# From list find closest number groups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need a formula for something a bit odd. I have random numbers that I get and I need them to be in 2 groups of 3, with both groups being as close to each other as possible, but no numbers can be duplicated. So, if I got say 1,2,3,44,12, 5,7, 9. I would have group A as 1,3 and 9 for a total of 13 and group b 2,5,7 for a total of 14. Sometimes I recieve 6 numbers, sometimes it is 16 numbers, usually 4 digit numbers. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a) there is no original effort shown and b) this belongs on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be too hard for Excel, but if you want to try, in hopes of pointing you in the right direction, here is some C# LINQ code to produce your answer:

```
var possibles = src.Combinations(3).SelectMany(ps => src.Except(ps).Combinations(3).Select(ps2 => new { ps, ps2 })).Select(psps2 => new { sum = psps2.ps.Sum()+psps2.ps2.Sum(), psps2.ps, psps2.ps2 });
var minsum = possibles.Min(psps2sum => psps2sum.sum);
var possibleans = possibles.Where(psps2sum => psps2sum.sum == minsum).First();
```

Note there are 20 possible pairs of groups that match your minimum such as (1,2,3),(5,7,9).

The `Combinations` extension is below:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k) {
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
      elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```